# Hover button and exchange SVG-filter in <use> with CSS

Tags: css, svg, hover, svg-filters

I have a shadow effect, which I made with a SVG filter to stay flexible for multiple variations of outlines. I apply this filter on `<use>`-elements and want to **exchange** this filter when the user hovers the parenting button.

**Exchange** seems to be important here, because applying a "new" filter on hover works across all major browsers. But changing it from a given filter to another filter seems only to work in Edge?

The CodePen example should bring light into the thing:
http://codepen.io/katerlouis/pen/pRmyoR

[image]

All I want is to switch between filters on hover using CSS.
Please no javascript solutions.

Strangely, sometimes clicking the button results in applying the filter which is supposed to come on hover.

I am on a late 2013 MBPr 15'' running El Capitan 10.11.6.
Also tested on other Macs in the Office, same results.
In Edge 14 (Browserstacks Chromeplugin) the buttons work fine.
Firefox (51), Chrome (56) and Safari (9.1.3) fail.

Comment: Sorry– I don't follow :O
The first filter (having feComposite aswell) applied via CSS alone works just fine. Please enlighten me :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a workaround.

1. Absolutely position the buttons (i.e one above the other)
2. Wrap the buttons in a container(`<div id="t">`)
3. Use the containers hover `.t:hover` event to hide the required button.

**Example:**

```css
body {
  padding: 40px;
  background: #003A63;
  color: white;
}

button {
  background: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

.button1 .outline {
  fill: white;
  filter: url(#button-neutral);
}

.button1 .fill {
  fill: #FFED00;
}

.button1:hover .outline {
  filter: url(#button-hover);
}

.button2 .outline {
  fill: white;
}

.button2 .fill {
  fill: #CD1719;
}

.button2:hover .outline {
  filter: url(#button-hover);
}

.t:hover .button1 {
  z-index: -1;
}

.button1,
.button12 {
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
Button with filter on both
<div class="t">
  <button class="button1">
 <svg>
  <use class="fill" xlink:href="#button-large-fill" />
  <use class="outline" xlink:href="#button-large-outline1" />
 </svg>
</button>

  <button class="button2">
 <svg>
  <use class="fill" xlink:href="#button-large-fill" />
  <use class="outline" xlink:href="#button-large-outline1" />
 </svg>
</button>
</div>

<svg version="1.1" class="hidden-svg">
 <defs>
  <filter id="button-neutral">

      <!-- Um den weißen rahmen des buttons nach oben zu schieben mit dem filter -->
      <feOffset in="SourceGraphic" dx="0" dy="-3" result="sourceCopy" />

      <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" dx="0" dy="1" result="innenSchatten" />

      <feFlood flood-color="gray" flood-opacity="0.8" result="innenSchatten-gefaerbt" />
      <feComposite in="innenSchatten-gefaerbt" in2="innenSchatten" operator="in" result="final" />

      <feBlend in="final" in2="" mode="multiply" /> 


   <feFlood flood-color="green" result="lol" />
   <feComposite in="lol" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="atop" result="lol2" /> 
      

      <!-- Put everything together. Blur then graphic. -->
   <feMerge>
    <feMergeNode in="final"/>
    <feMergeNode in="sourceCopy" />
   </feMerge>
  </filter>


  <filter id="button-hover">

      <!-- Um den weißen rahmen des buttons nach oben zu schieben mit dem filter -->
      <feOffset in="SourceGraphic" dx="0" dy="0" result="sourceCopy" />

      <feOffset in="SourceAlpha" dx="0" dy="2" result="innenSchatten" />

      <feFlood flood-color="gray" flood-opacity="1" result="innenSchatten-gefaerbt" />
      <feComposite in="innenSchatten-gefaerbt" in2="innenSchatten" operator="in" result="final" />

      <feBlend in="final" in2="" mode="multiply" /> 


   <feFlood flood-color="green" result="lol" />
   <feComposite in="lol" in2="SourceAlpha" operator="atop" result="lol2" /> 
      

      <!-- Put everything together. Blur then graphic. -->
   <feMerge>
    <feMergeNode in="final"/>
    <feMergeNode in="sourceCopy" />
   </feMerge>
  </filter>

 </defs>


 <symbol id="button-large-outline1" viewBox="0 0 255 48.9">

  <path d="M252.7,15.6c-1.3-3.2-3.3-6.1-5.8-8.4c-2.3-2.2-5.1-3.8-8-4.9c-0.4-0.1-0.7-0.3-1.1-0.4l-1.1-0.3c-0.8-0.2-1.5-0.3-2.3-0.4
    c-0.8-0.1-1.6-0.2-2.4-0.2c-0.8,0-1.5,0-2.2,0l-28.3,0.2c-2-0.1-4-0.2-6-0.2c-5.7-0.2-11.4-0.4-17.1-0.5l-8.6-0.2L161.2,0
    c-11.4-0.1-22.8,0-34.2,0.2C104.1,0.7,81.3,1.8,58.4,2C47,2.1,35.6,2.1,24.2,2c-0.7,0-1.4,0-2.2,0c-0.8,0-1.5,0-2.3,0.2
    c-0.8,0.1-1.5,0.2-2.2,0.4l-1.1,0.3c-0.4,0.1-0.7,0.2-1.1,0.4c-2.9,1-5.5,2.5-7.8,4.6c-2.3,2-4.1,4.6-5.4,7.4c-1.3,2.8-2,5.9-2.1,9
    c-0.2,6.2,2.3,12.6,6.9,17c0.3,0.3,0.6,0.5,0.9,0.8c4.2,4.1,9.9,6.7,16.2,6.7h51.1c17.3,0.2,34.6,0.3,51.8,0.2l17.1-0.1
    c3.1,0,6.2-0.1,9.3-0.1H232c12.7,0,23-10.3,23-23C255,22.1,254.1,18.7,252.7,15.6z M5,25.6c0-10.5,8.5-19,19-19h208
    c5.1,0,9.7,2,13.1,5.3c2.9,3.4,4.5,7.8,4.5,12.2c0,5.1-2.2,10-6,13.4c-1.8,1.7-4,3-6.4,3.9c-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.2-0.9,0.3l-0.9,0.2
    c-0.6,0.2-1.2,0.3-1.8,0.3c-0.6,0.1-1.2,0.1-1.9,0.2c-0.3,0-0.6,0-1,0l-1.1,0l-34.2-0.3l-20.9-0.1l-4.8-0.1l-8.6-0.2
    c-5.7-0.1-11.4-0.2-17.1-0.2l-17.1-0.1c-22.8-0.1-45.7,0.1-68.5,0.4C47,42,35.6,42.1,24.2,42.3l-1.1,0c-0.4,0-0.6,0-1,0
    c-0.6,0-1.2,0-1.9-0.1c-0.6-0.1-1.2-0.1-1.8-0.3l-0.9-0.2c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-0.9-0.3c-2.4-0.8-4.6-2-6.5-3.7
    c-1.4-1.2-2.5-2.6-3.5-4.1C5.6,31.1,5,28.5,5,25.6z" />

 </symbol>
 
 <symbol id="button-large-fill" viewBox="0 0 255 48.9">
  <path class="st0" d="M0.9,23.6c0-11.6,9.4-21,21-21h208c11.6,0,21,9.4,21,21c0,11.6-9.4,21-21,21h-208C10.3,44.6,0.9,35.2,0.9,23.6z
         "/>
 </symbol>

</svg>
```

Comment: Your workaround leaves a flash of white from the neutral button on the top. Of course that could be fixed aswell. Hiding and showing another outline on hover could be done in the same button, thus not needing an additional wrapper. But I am not looking for a workaround; I am interested in why exchanging the filter-value doesn't work in most modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Technically in SVG 1.1, filter is not a CSS property that can be applied to a SVG sub-element so this styling shouldn't work at all - never mind on hover. Various browsers are gradually implementing SVG 2 behavior which expands CSS stylability.

Workaround - apply the style classes to a wrapper div around the SVG, then filters switch just fine on hover. See below:

```css
#shapes {
  filter: url(#firstfilter);
}

#shapes:hover {
  filter: url(#secondfilter);
}
```

```html
<div id="shapes">
<svg>
  <defs>
    <filter id="firstfilter">
      <feColorMatrix type="matrix" values=".2 .2 .2 0 0 
                                           0 0 0 0 0 
                                           0 0 0 0 0 
                                           0 0 0 1 0"/>
    </filter>
      
     <filter id="secondfilter">
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2"/>
    </filter>   
      
  </defs>
    
  <path class="st0" d="M0.9,23.6c0-11.6,9.4-21,21-21h208c11.6,0,21,9.4,21,21c0,11.6-9.4,21-21,21h-208C10.3,44.6,0.9,35.2,0.9,23.6z" fill="blue"/>
  
  <path d="M252.7,15.6c-1.3-3.2-3.3-6.1-5.8-8.4c-2.3-2.2-5.1-3.8-8-4.9c-0.4-0.1-0.7-0.3-1.1-0.4l-1.1-0.3c-0.8-0.2-1.5-0.3-2.3-0.4
    c-0.8-0.1-1.6-0.2-2.4-0.2c-0.8,0-1.5,0-2.2,0l-28.3,0.2c-2-0.1-4-0.2-6-0.2c-5.7-0.2-11.4-0.4-17.1-0.5l-8.6-0.2L161.2,0
    c-11.4-0.1-22.8,0-34.2,0.2C104.1,0.7,81.3,1.8,58.4,2C47,2.1,35.6,2.1,24.2,2c-0.7,0-1.4,0-2.2,0c-0.8,0-1.5,0-2.3,0.2
    c-0.8,0.1-1.5,0.2-2.2,0.4l-1.1,0.3c-0.4,0.1-0.7,0.2-1.1,0.4c-2.9,1-5.5,2.5-7.8,4.6c-2.3,2-4.1,4.6-5.4,7.4c-1.3,2.8-2,5.9-2.1,9
    c-0.2,6.2,2.3,12.6,6.9,17c0.3,0.3,0.6,0.5,0.9,0.8c4.2,4.1,9.9,6.7,16.2,6.7h51.1c17.3,0.2,34.6,0.3,51.8,0.2l17.1-0.1
    c3.1,0,6.2-0.1,9.3-0.1H232c12.7,0,23-10.3,23-23C255,22.1,254.1,18.7,252.7,15.6z M5,25.6c0-10.5,8.5-19,19-19h208
    c5.1,0,9.7,2,13.1,5.3c2.9,3.4,4.5,7.8,4.5,12.2c0,5.1-2.2,10-6,13.4c-1.8,1.7-4,3-6.4,3.9c-0.3,0.1-0.6,0.2-0.9,0.3l-0.9,0.2
    c-0.6,0.2-1.2,0.3-1.8,0.3c-0.6,0.1-1.2,0.1-1.9,0.2c-0.3,0-0.6,0-1,0l-1.1,0l-34.2-0.3l-20.9-0.1l-4.8-0.1l-8.6-0.2
    c-5.7-0.1-11.4-0.2-17.1-0.2l-17.1-0.1c-22.8-0.1-45.7,0.1-68.5,0.4C47,42,35.6,42.1,24.2,42.3l-1.1,0c-0.4,0-0.6,0-1,0
    c-0.6,0-1.2,0-1.9-0.1c-0.6-0.1-1.2-0.1-1.8-0.3l-0.9-0.2c-0.3-0.1-0.6-0.2-0.9-0.3c-2.4-0.8-4.6-2-6.5-3.7
    c-1.4-1.2-2.5-2.6-3.5-4.1C5.6,31.1,5,28.5,5,25.6z" fill="red" /> 

</svg>
      
 </div>
```

Comment: The filter only should apply to one `<use>` inside the SVG.

Comment: split the paths into two separate svgs

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this [workaround on CodePen](https://codepen.io/shshaw/pen/wWGNWX). It uses opacity with the hover state. I needed to handle transparency in my filters so modified it slightly. I also moved the styling to an external css sheet. I like this better than doing additional `div` wraps as the hover state can be applied to an polygon rather than a rectangle.

```
<style>
    #group {
        cursor: pointer;
    }
    #group #poly-off {
        opacity: 1;
    }
    #group #poly-on {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    #group:hover #poly-off {
        opacity: 0;
    }
    #group:hover #poly-on {
        opacity: 1;
    }
</style>

<svg>
    <defs>
        <filter id="off">
        <filter id="on">
        <path d="..." id="path"/>
    </defs>
    <g id="group">
        <use id="poly-off" filter="url(#off)" xlink:href="#path"/>
        <use id="poly-on" filter="url(#on)" xlink:href="#path"/>
        <use fill-opacity="0.5" fill="#ff0000" xlink:href="#path"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```